# convert rows into column in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some problem when converting rows into column in codeigniter, i have a sql query to convert row into column using group_concat...

this is my query

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'MAX(IF(idPertanyaan = ''',
  idPertanyaan,
  ''', jawaban, NULL)) AS ',
  idPertanyaan
)
) INTO @sql
FROM kuesioner;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT idmember, ', @sql, ' FROM kuesioner GROUP BY idmember');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

I can't turn that query into codeigniter model
please tell me create model with this query or how to convert dynamic row into column... thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create a stored procedure in your database, then within your Model you can do this:

```
public function yourFunction() {
    $query = $this->db->query("CALL `your_stored_procedure()`");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: almost, but when I call the procedure in controller, it say php error "array to string conversion" and unable to select database... need help